# Aurora Events Not Appearing In SNS Topic?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora PostgreSQL database which I am trying to set up to send all events for the cluster or instances to an email address. All resources are being defined in Terraform.

I've created the database, and when I add the subscription, I get an email saying to verify, and then I get an email indicating I am now subscribed to events on the cluster/instances.

But after that I don't get anything else, even though the AWS console shows events occurring every hour. SNS reports that it gets no events other than the first event either.

I've double-checked permissions and everything seems correct, but obviously it isn't working still. What am I missing to get this to work, or where can I go to help debug this issue? I'm including some of the Terraform code below for reference. I've expanded permissions a bit larger than normal just to try to get things to work, but that hasn't helped.

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "writer_rds_sns_encryption_key" {
  key_usage = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
  policy = <<POLICY
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account}:root",
          "${var.rds_role}"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
  enable_key_rotation = true
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "cluster_event_topic" {
  name              = "..."
  kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.writer_rds_sns_encryption_key.id
}

#tfsec:ignore:aws-iam-no-policy-wildcards
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "event_subscription_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sns:AddPermission",
      "sns:DeleteTopic",
      "sns:GetDataProtectionPolicy",
      "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
      "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
      "sns:Publish",
      "sns:PutDataProtectionPolicy",
      "sns:RemovePermission",
      "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
      "sns:Subscribe"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.rds.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "event_subscription_policy_attach" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.cluster_event_topic.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.event_subscription_policy.json
}

resource "aws_db_event_subscription" "cluster_event_subscription" {
  name             = "..."
  sns_topic        = aws_sns_topic.cluster_event_topic.arn

  source_type      = "db-cluster"
  source_ids       = [aws_rds_cluster.aurora_db.id]

  event_categories = [
    "failover",
    "migration",
    "failure",
    "notification",
    "serverless",
    "creation",
    "deletion",
    "maintenance",
    "configuration change",
    "global-failover"
  ]
  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      aws_rds_cluster.aurora_db.id
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "audit_topic_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.cluster_event_topic.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there were multiple parts of this that were wrong.

First, not all events shown in the RDS console have categories, so they will not be notified on, even if they occur. The hourly notifications about log rolling fits into this, as does a lot of other notifications. We found that changing the enhanced monitoring interval provided a good safe testing mechanism that did cause a notification to be raised.

Secondly, for some reason, a publisher to an encrypted SNS topic needs to have decrypt permissions along with GenerateDataKey* permissions to encrypt their message. Thus, the key policy we should've been using looks like the following:

```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account}:root",
          "${var.rds_role}"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
        "kms:GenerateDataKeyPair",
        "kms:GenerateDataKeyPairWithoutPlaintext"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once we updated the key policy to the above and then started triggering notifications that actually led to emails, we got the emails successfully. Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into this issue as well!